# IIS Shared Configuration Webfarm - Error when dynamically updating bindings

Tags: file, azure, iis, entity, azure-storage-files

First time posting a question so apologies for anything I'm doing wrong.

I have a webfarm of 4 IIS servers running windows server 2016 which uses an azure file storage account for its webfiles. It also save its shared configuration files to the same azure file storage account. This webfarm is then behind an azure load balancer.

Everything works fine, until part of the website code adds an IIS binding. This then causes all the servers to display the **error** below:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework,...etc" The parameter
>   is incorrect. (Image attached for full error).
>   [image]

The only way to resolve this error is to clear the asp.net temporary files from the C drive of all the servers and run `IISRESET` on each box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to update your web.config file:  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false"/>

Comment: Thanks for the comment Zahid, i already have a similar line as below, will the extra params cause issues?

<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: Try removing extra parameters are simply replace your web.config with the one I shared above.

Comment: I tried changing the config but not luck. I've also noticed that just opening the web.config, changing nothing and pressing save, causes the same error. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a mystery but the following changes have resolved the issue. I'm not sure which combination has fixed it, but this might help someone who has a similar issue.

1. Recreate website in IIS using new App pool.
2. Removed individual IIS bindings and replaced with wildcard (we had a really old-school system before where we had 100s of binding, maybe one of these was corrupted).

Thanks for your help!